# File Exception while trying to upload file via spock test

Tags: spring-boot, spock

I'm getting the below exception while trying to test from a spock test to upload a file.
How can I fix this?

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided`

Rest End point

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/file", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void uploadAssessment(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
  System.out.println("Reached here with file ");
}
```

My Test

```java
LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> parameters =
  new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
parameters.add(
  "file",
  new org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource("abc.txt")
);
    
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    
HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> entity =
  new HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>>(parameters, headers);
    
ResponseEntity<String> response =
  restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Object.class);
```

Comment: Would you mind turning your example code into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? The test does not call `uploadAssessment`, so how does that method end up being called? Where does `restTemplate` come from? What value does `uri` have? Isolated snippets are not classes, even classes are not an MCVE, i.e. nobody can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ping! Could you solve your problem? Then please, write an answer and self-accept it. Otherwise, please improve the question so as to get this off the table. Thank you.